# Convert Array values into Percentages Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a pie chart which references values from an array.

I want to display these array values as a percentage. How do I do this?

The Plugin that I used to generate this pie chart is `chart.js`

Javascript for reference:

```
success : function (data){
    console.log(data);

    var categoryname = ["Drain", "Building", "Pest", "Broken Utilities", 
    "Littering", "Leakage", "Lighting"];
    var category = [];
    var amount = [];

    for (var i in data) { 
        category.push(categoryname[data[i].Category]);
        amount.push (data[i].CaseNum);
    }
    var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: amount,
                backgroundColor: [
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)"
                    ],
                label: 'Dataset 1'
            }],
                labels: category
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };
    var ctx = $("#mycanvas");       
    var graph = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

Php for reference:

```
$query = "SELECT categoryID as 'Category', COUNT(Case.categoryID) as 'CaseNum' 
FROM `Case` WHERE CaseTime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND 
now() GROUP BY categoryID ORDER BY categoryID";

$result = $conn->query($query);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}


$conn->close();

print json_encode($data);
```

Piechart Image Example: [image: Piechart Image Example]

Comment: In `data: amount`, what is the `amount` value format? Decimals? Integers? You might need to create function helpers to create the percentages

Comment: @rachmatsasongko They are in Integers

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
success : function (data){
    console.log(data);

    var integerAmount = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        integerAmount.push(data[i].CaseNum);
    }
    var sum = integerAmount.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    var categoryname = ["Drain", "Building", "Pest", "Broken Utilities", "Littering", "Leakage", "Lighting"];
    var category = [];
    var amount = [];
    for (var i in data) {
        category.push(categoryname[data[i].Category]);
        amount.push (integerAmount[i]/sum*100+'%');
    }

    // rest of the script
}
```

The idea is to store the Integers value first from the `data` object. Then sum the total value. Last we push the actual percentage value and adding the `%` to the `amount` data for pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of numbers it is as simple as reducing the array in to a sum and mapping each element to be divided by the sum.

```
let a = [123,32,22,23,64]
let sum = a.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
let a_percentage = a.map(e => e/sum*100)
```

You can then format it as you want.